# REDIRECCIÓN DE AL INICIAR SESIÓN

Tags: php, login, sesiones

que tal compañeros. Me encuentro creando un login de usuarios con php, con sesiones de usuario en PHP, pero aun estoy verde. 
En local todo funciona muy bien, pero cuando lo subo a hosting no me hace la REDIRECCIÓN y se me queda la pantalla en blanco y tampoco me lanza ningún error.

Esto es lo que tengo.

**conexión a la DB**:

```
 <?php
     include ('../global/conexion.php');
     include ('index.php');
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
```

**Formulario de login:**

```
    <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" 
       action="index">

       <span class="login100-form-title">
         <h2 class="text-color">Login clientes</h2>
       </span>
       <a href="http://localhost/edinarweb"><<< Volver a EdinarWeb</a><br><br>

       <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" id="correo"  data-validate="El email es requerido: ex@abc.xyz">

       <input class="input100" type="text" id="correo" name="txtEmail" placeholder="Correo">
       <span class="focus-input100"></span>
       <span class="symbol-input100">
         <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </div>

      <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input" data-validate="La contraseña es requerida">
      <input class="input100" type="password" id="passw" name="txtPassword" placeholder="Contrase&ntilde;a">
      <span class="focus-input100"></span>
      <span class="symbol-input100">
         <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <input class="login100-form-btn" type="submit" value="IDENTIFICARME" 
        name="btnLogin" id="register-btn" /> 
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Y este es el script de validación que en debería estar redireccionando al usuaerio al la sección de autentificación, que como dije en local me esta funcionando bien, pero al subirlo al hosting no.

**Script de validacion de usuario y contraseña:**

```
 <?php 

    //echo "Hola estoy en login";

       if (isset($_POST["btnLogin"])) {

          include('../global/conexion.php');
          $txtEmail=($_POST['txtEmail']);
          $txtPassword=($_POST['txtPassword']);

          $sentenciaSQL=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblusuarios WHERE correo=:correo AND password=:password");

          $sentenciaSQL->bindParam("correo",$txtEmail,PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $sentenciaSQL->bindParam("password",$txtPassword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
          $sentenciaSQL->execute();
          $registro=$sentenciaSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
          //print_r($registro);

        $numeroRegistros=$sentenciaSQL->rowCount();

        if ($numeroRegistros>=1) {

            session_start();

            $_SESSION['usuario']=$registro;


            header('Location: ../secure-access/googleautenticador/index.php');
    }else{

            echo "<h2 style='color: green'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Oh Oh!!!....<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
            Lo sentimos mucho,<br>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            No se encontraron registros en nuestra base de datos...</h2>";
        }

       //echo "<br> hay que validar el correo y la contraseña";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Ya encontré el error. Se encontraba en el:**

```
header ("Location:");
```

Pues al parecer el header de php no se puede usar para direccionar una página en cualquier punto. Únicamente se puede utilizar si es exactamente la primera salida que se envía, si no lo es no funcionará (por tanto no se puede usar en un punto intermedio de una web)

**Así que opte por redireccionar con javascript de esta forma:**

**Yo tenia:**

```
header('Location: ../secure-access/googleautenticador/index.php');
```

**Y lo cambie por:**

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">
                //alert("Probando vamos a proceder a redireccionar");
                window.location.assign("https://app.mywebsite.com/secure-access/googleautenticador/index.php");
                </script>';
```

**Se me paso en la vez pasada colocar la ruta original, que es esta de ejemplo:**

```
 https://app.mywebsite.com secure-access/googleautenticador/index.php
```

**así que en la solucion la coloque para que quede más claro por si a alguien le puede ayudar.**